# Unable to retain the format in copying from one excel file to another

Tags: perl, spreadsheet, xls

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

# Open an existing file with SaveParser
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $template = $parser->Parse('template.xls');

my $parser1   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $template1 = $parser1->Parse('test_perl.xls');

my $worksheet11 = $template->worksheet(0);

 $template1->AddWorksheet('New Data');

my $worksheet22 = $template1->worksheet(0);

my $cellz; my $valua;my $format_number;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < 400; $i++) {
        for (my $j = 0; $j < 20; $j++) {
            $cellz = $worksheet11->get_cell( $i, $j );
            if($cellz){
                $valua = $cellz->unformatted(); $format_number = $cellz->{FormatNo};
                $worksheet22->AddCell($i, $j, $valua,$format_number);
            }
        }   
    }

my $workbook;
$workbook = $template1->SaveAs('newfile1.xls');
```

I want to copy content from one excel file to another retaining the format too. Here by format I mean fill color, border, bold, italic, etc. I have written a code for this where I extract the value and format number from one excel file and simply write in the other excel sheet. I have referred the following link for that.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser

The problem is that it is not retaining the format. I think the problem is that the format number is not universal which means that a format number means two different things in two different excel files.
When I run this code I get the error

> Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /pkg/qct/software/perl/5.18.0_test/lib/site_perl/5.18.0/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 2383.

According to me, it means that the extracted format number doesn't mean anything to other file. Please let me know solution to this problem

Basically what my problem is that I have modified two xls file using Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser and I want to merge those two xls files using Perl. Please suggest a way of merging two xls files using Perl in any other way such that formatting is retained. Please suggest non-Perl way too using some other coding language.

This question is also cross posted on perl-monks : 
https://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=11101251

Comment: @simbabque can you please try running this code and suggest a solution if you know

Comment: All I did was fix your wrong use of markdown in the post. I've had a look and I think you are right, the format number is specific to each individual file, based on how XLS files work. I think you need to deep-copy the formats individually from the first to the second file. Make sure you only copy each format once.

Comment: Can you please explain what deep-copying of formats mean and how to do it ?
Also, is there any better perl or non-perl way to merge two xls files

Comment: You have to get the format object for the cell you want to copy in the old file, then get all its properties and use that to make a new format in the new file. You should cache the format numbers you have already copied so you don't get duplicates in the new file. I think the number of possible formats is limited. If you look at the documentation of the formats in Spreadsheet::ParseExcel you will see the font is inside the format and also has properties, so that needs to be copied to, again probably with a cache. I don't know any alternative solution. Good luck.

Comment: FYI to potential answerers: This question has been cross-posted to PerlMonks at https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11101251

Comment: Actually that's me

Comment: Yes, it is you. That's what "cross-posting" is - you posted the same question to multiple sites. It's considered polite to tell people about that so they can check the other sites before answering, in case you already have a solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the above problem is same as what @simbabque said in the comments. You have to extract all properties of the format of every cell and create new format for each cell using these extracted properties. As very correctly said by @simbabque, the number of properties are fixed. Please see the below link:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel#Format

I am also attaching the final code for merging two xls files. In this code two xls files are taken as argument and are merged into first one and saved with name "testing.xls".

Thanks @simbabque for your help. Please post your comment as a answer and I will accept it as a solution.

Following is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

print "FILE 1 $ARGV[0]"."\n";
my $parser1   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $template1 = $parser1->Parse($ARGV[0])  or die "Unable to open first xls file";

my $func_worksheet_count = $template1->worksheet_count();

my $parser2   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $template2 = $parser2->Parse($ARGV[1])  or die "Unable to open second xls file";

my $test_worksheet_count = $template2->worksheet_count();

print "FILE 2 $ARGV[1]"."\n";


my $worksheet22;
my $worksheet11;
my $sheet_name;

 for (my $i = 0; $i < $test_worksheet_count; $i++) {
    $worksheet22 = $template2->worksheet($i);
    $sheet_name = $worksheet22->get_name();
        print $sheet_name."\n";
    $template1->AddWorksheet($sheet_name);
 } 

 my $font;
 my $AlignH;
 my $AlignV; 
 my $Indent;
 my $Wrap;
 my $Shrink;
 my $Rotate;
 my $JustLast;
 my $ReadDir;
 my $BdrStyle;
 my $BdrColor;
 my $BdrDiag;
 my $Fill;
 my $Lock;
 my $Hidden;
 my $Style;

 my $iFmt;
 my $format;
my $iF1;





 for (my $k = 0; $k < $test_worksheet_count; $k++) {

    $worksheet22 = $template2->worksheet($k);
    $worksheet11 = $template1->worksheet($func_worksheet_count+$k); 


    my $cellz; my $valua;my $format_number;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        for (my $j = 0; $j < 30; $j++) {
            $cellz = $worksheet22->get_cell( $i, $j );
            if($cellz){
                $valua = $cellz->value(); $format_number = $cellz->{FormatNo};
                $format = $cellz->get_format(); 
                 $font = $format->{Font};
                 $AlignH = $format->{AlignH};
                 $AlignV = $format->{AlignV}; 
                 $Indent = $format->{Indent};
                 $Wrap = $format->{Wrap};
                 $Shrink = $format->{Shrink};
                 $Rotate = $format->{Rotate};
                 $JustLast = $format->{JustLast};
                 $ReadDir = $format->{ReadDir};
                 $BdrStyle = $format->{BdrStyle};
                 $BdrColor = $format->{BdrColor};
                 $BdrDiag = $format->{BdrDiag};
                 $Fill = $format->{Fill};
                 $Lock = $format->{Lock};
                 $Hidden = $format->{Hidden};
                 $Style = $format->{Style};


                 $iFmt =
                $template1->AddFormat(
                    Font => $font,
                    AlignH => $AlignH,
                    AlignV => $AlignV,
                    Indent => $Indent,
                    Wrap => $Wrap,
                    Shrink => $Shrink,
                    Rotate => $Rotate,
                    JustLast => $JustLast,
                    ReadDir => $ReadDir,
                    BdrStyle => $BdrStyle,
                    BdrColor => $BdrColor,
                    BdrDiag => $BdrDiag,
                    Fill => $Fill,
                    Lock => $Lock,
                    Hidden => $Hidden,
                    Style     =>  $Style,
                );


                $worksheet11->AddCell($i, $j, $valua, $iFmt);
            }
        }   
    }
 }



my $workbook3 = $template1->SaveAs("testing.xls");
```